# authenticated visualforce page for community

Tags: visualforce, community

I am setting up a community, but I need to create custom visual pages for every single page in the community. I have two questions.

1. Is there any benefit to using community vs. site.com, since every page is custom visualforce page and a custom template
2. I have already created a couple of basic visualforce pages, but they are both available for non-authenticated users. I have tried to set the profile in the security of the page to community login user, but that hasn't made any difference. How can I enforce authentication for a visualforce page in community?

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds like you want a Community with visualforce pages.
2. Enable them for the community login user profile, but not the guest profile (community profile).